# Deploying Django with SQLite on Azure

Tags: python, django, sqlite, azure, azure-devops

I have built a prototype Django app with SQLite that I want to deploy to Azure. When I go through the steps from my Azure portal (selecting a Django template when creating the app, then connecting it to my Github repository), I end up with a webpage that looks like this:

http://lowrentgent.azurewebsites.net/

If I go into Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online), I can see that my files have come over from Github. However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here and make it so that my own page shows up here instead of the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can build up an App Service with an empty template. Create a virtual environment in your application repository, then deploy to Azure via Git local or GitHub.

If you are on Windows, you can use Visual Studio and PTVS tool, to dev and deploy your Django applications on Azure with a ease.

You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/ for details.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.